# How to change Arabic Currency into English Currency in Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using WordPress Woocommerce. My store Currency is in Saudi Riyal which is write in Arabic language. I wanted to change this Arabic Language into English Language for example: SAR or SR. Please tell me solution of it.

Here is link: http://www.classic-polos.com/product/polo-basic/

And I have also attached screenshot of page. Screenshot of my Problem:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

the only way to display the letters in latin like it used to be before the WooCommerce update is to use the same old trick, even WPML won't help translating the currency in this case, just add a custom currency in the theme **functions.php** file as following:

[Add a custom currency / symbol](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/add-a-custom-currency-symbol/)

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_currencies', 'add_my_currency' );

function add_my_currency( $currencies ) {
     $currencies['ABC'] = __( 'Currency name', 'woocommerce' );
     return $currencies;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_currency_symbol', 'add_my_currency_symbol', 10, 2);

function add_my_currency_symbol( $currency_symbol, $currency ) {
     switch( $currency ) {
          case 'ABC': $currency_symbol = '$'; break;
     }
     return $currency_symbol;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply change it by adding a woocommerce hook using your child theme or a custom plugin like this

```
add_filter('woocommerce_currency_symbol','change_existing_currency_symbol', 10, 2);
function change_existing_currency_symbol( $currency_symbol, $currency ) {
    switch( $currency ) {
        case 'SAR': $currency_symbol =  "$"; // $ is now your new currency symbol
        break;
    }
    return $currency_symbol;
}
```

Note : your can also change it without code simply by using woocommerce dashboard 
go to

> WooCommerce > Settings > General > Currency Options

you can change it from there :)

Answer (score -2):

You can manually change currency from word press admin section.please refer below URL:

[Change shop currency woo commerce](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/shop-currency/)